# Typeclass Trouble with Haskell Probability Monad

Tags: haskell, monads, typeclass

I am trying to write a monad for discrete random variables in haskell. The type class looks something like this:

```
{- LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances #-}

class (Num w, Monad m) => MonadDiscrete w m where
  sample :: [(a, w)] -> m a
```

I'd like to make two instances of this. The first is like the list monad:

```
newtype Discrete w a = Discrete [(a, w)]

instance (Num w) => Monad (Discrete w) where
  ...

instance (Num w) => MonadDiscrete w (Discrete w) where
  sample = Discrete
```

The second is using the PRNG in MonadRandom:

```
instance (MonadRandom m) => MonadDiscrete Rational m where
  sample = fromList
```

However, if I try to do something like:

```
x :: (Num w, MonadDiscrete w m) => m String
x = sample [("x", 1)]
```

GHC gives me an error:

> Could not deduce (MonadDiscrete w0 m)
>     arising from the ambiguity check for `it'
>   from the context (MonadDiscrete w m)
>     bound by the inferred type for`it': MonadDiscrete w m => m [Char]
>     at :7:1-17
>   The type variable `w0' is ambiguous
>   Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
>   Note: there are several potential instances:
>     instance Num w => MonadDiscrete w (Discrete w)
>       -- Defined at lib/Discrete.hs:64:10
>     instance Control.Monad.Random.Class.MonadRandom m =>
>              MonadDiscrete Rational m
>       -- Defined at lib/Discrete.hs:58:10
>   When checking that`it'
>     has the inferred type `forall w (m :: * -> *).
>                            MonadDiscrete w m =>
>                            m [Char]'
>   Probable cause: the inferred type is ambiguous

I've tried all sorts of things including adding FunDeps or making w an associated type, but all fail.

Comment: Could you fix your code sample? The instance for `MonadDiscrete (Discrete w)` needs another type parameter... That said, have you tried disambiguating the constant `1` in `x`, like so: `(1::Int)`?

Comment: The answer is going to be `FunctionalDependencies`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the declaration

```
class (Num w, Monad m) => MonadDiscrete w m where
    sample :: [(a, w)] -> m a
```

doesn't express the fact that for a given discrete probability monad, the choice of the type to represent weights is fixed. For example, in your `Discrete` example, for any choice of `w`, the `Discrete w` monad can only deal with probability weights of type `w`.

Because this is not expressed in the above declaration, it is possible to define two `MonadDiscrete` instances that only differ in the choice of `w`, but not in the choice of `m`. This means 
in the definition of `sample`, the `MonadDiscrete` instance cannot be resolved from `m` alone.

The proper way to solve this is to use a functional dependency or a `MonadDiscrete`-associated type family to express the fact that the choice of `m` uniquely determines the choice of `w`. Here's an example that uses functional dependencies:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, FunctionalDependencies #-}

class (Num w, Monad m) => MonadDiscrete w m | m -> w where
    sample :: [(a, w)] -> m a

newtype Discrete w a = Discrete [(a, w)]

instance (Num w) => Monad (Discrete w)
instance (Num w) => MonadDiscrete w (Discrete w)

x :: (Num w, MonadDiscrete w m) => m String
x = sample [("x", 1)]
```

Because `m` determines `w`, even though `w` doesn't occur in the type of `x`, it can still be uniquely resolved, so the correct `MonadDiscrete` instance can be picked.

Here's the same solution using type families:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleContexts #-}

class (Num (Weight m), Monad m) => MonadDiscrete m where
    type Weight m :: *
    sample :: [(a, Weight m)] -> m a

newtype Discrete w a = Discrete [(a, w)]

instance (Num w) => Monad (Discrete w)

instance (Num w) => MonadDiscrete (Discrete w) where
    type Weight (Discrete w) = w
    sample = undefined

x :: (MonadDiscrete m) => m String
x = sample [("x", 1)]
```

This one feels a bit different, because here instead of spelling out the dependency, we simply say that part of being a `MonadDiscrete` instance is saying what type is representing `Weight`s.

Comment: Please could you give an equivalent formulation using type families?

Comment: Done; but I feel the fundep one is closer to Vlad's original code.

Comment: You didn't include the second (MonadRandom m) instance. Adding that causes ghc to complain: "Overlapping instances for MonadDiscrete Rational m". A similar error occurs with type families. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Contemplate what happens when someone adds a `MonadRandom` instance for `Discrete`... Look at `Control.Applicative.WrappedMonad` for a pattern of workaround for this kind of problem.

Comment: I think the problem is that effectively what I'm trying to say is "if it isn't already a MonadDiscrete, but is a MonadRandom, then use this to make it a MonadDiscrete", but this isn't really expressible in Haskell. This problem has caused me to read all sorts of stuff on type classes. I've found out about these "ConstraintKinds", but haven't grokked them well enough to determine whether they apply here (iirc they allow you to do things like make Set a Monad that you weren't able to do before).

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured out that I don't actually want

```
instance (MonadRandom m) => MonadDiscrete Rational m where
  sample = fromList
```

But instead:

```
instance RandomGen g => MonadDiscrete Rational (Rand g) where
  sample = fromList
```

Since my aim is to use a particular existing implementation, as opposed to all possible MonadRandom instances.